# Efficiently cleaning data while importing CSV file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am importing a dataset with Python's Pandas that unfortunately needs some cleaning. After importing, I need to remove all quotes and spaces in two columns (`alpha2` and `alpha3`). This is currently how I do this:

```
# Add alpha2 country codes to custom dataset to normalize data
country_codes = pd.read_csv('datasets/country_codes.csv').rename(columns = {'Alpha-2 code':'alpha2', 'Alpha-3 code':'alpha3'})
# Remove commas and spaces from dataset
country_codes['alpha2'] = country_codes['alpha2'].str.replace('"', '')
country_codes['alpha2'] = country_codes['alpha2'].str.replace(' ', '')
country_codes['alpha3'] = country_codes['alpha3'].str.replace('"', '')
country_codes['alpha3'] = country_codes['alpha3'].str.replace(' ', '')
```

In my oppinion, this is a bit ugly since I need 5 rules for some simple commands. Can this be done more efficiently/with less code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.replace` with a `regex` as follows:

```
country_codes[['alpha2', 'alpha3']].replace(r'"|\s','', 
                                                regex=True,
                                                inplace=True)
```

---

The full code will look like this:

```
country_codes = pd.read_csv('datasets/country_codes.csv').rename(columns = {'Alpha-2 code': 'alpha2', 'Alpha-3 code':'alpha3'})
country_codes[['alpha2', 'alpha3']].replace(r'"|\s','', 
                                            regex=True,
                                            inplace=True)
```

However, as refered by @Jeff in the comments below, it's better not to use `inplace=True` instead you can do this:

```
country_codes[['alpha2', 'alpha3']] = country_codes[['alpha2', 'alpha3']].replace(r'"|\s','', 
                                                regex=True)
```

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for further details.

Comment: using inplace=True on a chained expression is not idiomatic and it might only work sometimes; rather simply return the new values